# How to get the value of an object present inside a div with id using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view page where i have an object inside a div like :-

```
<div id="booking_id"><%@booking_id%></div>
```

I want to get the value of @booking_id to be passed in AJAX data params and my ajax function is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selecthotel2").change(function(){
    var room = $(this).children(":selected").val();
    var params = $('#booking_id').filter('#booking_id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/rooms/assign_room",
      data: {
               room,
               params
            }
    })
  });
});

</script>
```

But i am not getting the @booking_id value to be passed to another action.
I think i am going somewhat wrong in the ajax syntax,kindly help.

Comment: $('#booking_id').html() will fetch you the contents inside div which in your case is your booking id.

Comment: so replace ` var params = $('#booking_id').filter('#booking_id').val();` with
`var params=$('#booking_id').html()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it's not working , the value of params going is like this :- Parameters: {"room"=>"1", "params"=>""}

Comment: can you elaborate further as `$('#booking_id').html()` or `$('#booking_id').html()` will fetch the content inside div.put an  `alert(params)` then tell me what value are you getting

Comment: Yah the alert(params) gives nothing . Its just like:- localhost:3000 says:

Comment: ok did you try `$('#booking_id').text()` ?

Comment: Yah i got it . The value wasn't really coming to the script .The alert(params) did helped me to check it though.!  Thank you @Shahshank

Comment: please correct the spelling ;) @Debasish

Answer (score 0):

change
`$('#booking_id').filter('#booking_id').val();`

to simply

`$('#booking_id').text();`

Currently your code is trying to look *inside* $("#booking_id") for another element with the same ID, instead of taking the value of $('#booking_id') itself.

Also since $("#booking_id") is a div and not an input, I think you need to get the contents using text(), not val().

Comment: I am sorry that didn't worked , is there any other way by which i can send the object with the data in ajax ! The value going in params is :- "params"=>" "

Comment: @Debasish you should check the value in jquery first.Whether you are getting the correct value. Then we can further solve the problem. put an alert to params variable and see the output